# Windows form not showing control C#

Tags: c#

I have made a windows form application (*which has been running fine for more than couple of weeks*). Now I wanted to add another form in it (*which should be displayed to show extra properties of item whose value is being shown in rich textbox*)

Here is my code for double click (*to show details window*):

```
private void richTextBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Using parameterized constructor since I need an input from parent form
    Form2 formETView = new Form2(richTextBox1.Text.Substring(1, 15));
    formETView.Show();
}
```

As a reference, constructor of Form2 is:

```
public Form2(string p)
{
    // TODO: Complete member initialization
    trans_ID = p;            
}
```

But it shows only this screen:

[image]

While actual screen has couple of controls:

[image]

Any help in this regard will be really appreciated.

P.S: *Is the approach to use parameterized constructor to pass data as argument in child window incorrect? Please let me know if it's the case.*

Comment: Use `public Form2(string p) : this()` so you call default ctor that calls `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: My bad!! Thank you so much. Can you please tell whether its the right approach to use parameterized constructor for arguments passing or not?

Comment: I see no problem in using parameterized ctors in forms, just make sure you had a parameterless one for the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
public Form2(string p) : this()
```

This way you call default constructor that calls `InitializeComponents`.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `InitializeComponent()` in your constructor function. That initializes all the controls of the form.